# Routes loading from app/http/routes.php instead of routes/web.php after Migration from 4.2 to 5.5

Tags: laravel, migration

I successfully migrated a project from Laravel version 4.2 to 5.5 which is currently on bug fixing phase. I have one issue, the routes is still loading from app/http/routes.php instead of routes/web.php.

Has anyone faced this situation? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: try clearning all the cache and dumpautoload

Comment: I tried, It didn't work. Do i need to register the web.php somewhere in the application? Making the app understand to load routes from web.php ?

Comment: How did you migrate it? Because from 4.2 to 5.5 seems a helluva migration to me.

Comment: @Amarnasan At the beginning from 4.2 to 5.0 I used this tutorial,

http://slashnode.com/definitive-laravel-4-to-laravel-5-migration-guide/
> I found out that it was also used for developing laravelshift.com

And for the rest of the versions I followed from official doc.